# How to exit from tsc "watch" mode gracefully?

Tags: typescript

I have a number of build scripts which go like

```
# some setup...
tsc blahblahblah
# Do stuff with the generated JS
```

I'd like to enable watch mode for convenience when developing, but when I `ctrl-c` out of `tsc --watch` it exits the whole script, so I don't get any of the post-compile actions.  Is there a way I can tell `tsc` to stop more gracefully?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fix this in your build script. The only difference is which exit code was sent, so you might want to look into how you can make your build script not completely exit if one command failed.